# Disable superfish on resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, superfish

I'm trying to combine the Superfish jQuery plugin with Nathan Smith's adapt.js snippet, which dynamically loads in different CSS files depending on browser width. I want to disable/replace/something the Superfish menu when in mobile mode, because drop-downs don't make any sense there. I've attempted to detect the change and disable the menu, but I need it to re-enable when the window is resized wide again.

Here's what I have:

```
function htmlId(i, width) {
    document.documentElement.id = 'pagesize_' + i;
}

var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
  path: '/css/',
  dynamic: true,
  callback: htmlId,
  range: [
    '0px    to 760px  = mobile.css',
    '760px  = 960_12.css'
  ]
};

function sfMenu() {
    $("#pagesize_1 ul.sf-menu").superfish({ 
        delay:       800,
        animation:   {opacity:'show'},
        speed:       'fast',
        autoArrows:  true,
        dropShadows: true
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    sfMenu();
});
```

The rationale was to change the id of the html element on `resize` (between `pagesize_0` and `pagesize_1` - which works) and to use descendent selectors in CSS to disable the menu, but that doesn't work. I tried rerunning `sfMenu()` on `resize` (code not shown above), but it doesn't seem to inspect the changed DOM, realise `pagesize_1` no longer exists, then fail gracefully (which I think would achieve the effect I'm after).

Any thoughts? Ideally I'd like to destroy the `superfish` function on resize-to-mobile, then re-instate it when the screen is large again.

Comment: I've tried using detach() and append() but I'm having no luck - I can't get appen() to work properly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

SuperFish has a 'destroy' method (certainly in latest 1.7.3 version) that you could call depending on screen size to disable it and then re-style the navigation using CSS media queries. You could also then call the 'init' method of SuperFish when you wanted to enable it again:

```
var sf, body;
var breakpoint = 600;
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    body = $('body');
    sf = $('ul.sf-menu');
    if(body.width() >= breakpoint) {
      // enable superfish when the page first loads if we're on desktop
      sf.superfish();
    }
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(body.width() >= breakpoint && !sf.hasClass('sf-js-enabled')) {
            // you only want SuperFish to be re-enabled once (sf.hasClass)
            sf.superfish('init');
        } else if(body.width() < breakpoint) {
            // smaller screen, disable SuperFish
            sf.superfish('destroy');
        }
    });
});
```

This should hopefully explain what I'm talking about :)

http://cdpn.io/jFBtw

Comment: I had similar task to disable sf menu on specific screen size and enable on other and this answer helped to achieve right result..

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing around with the same thing, going from horizontal nav-bar style (window wider than subnav) to vertical drop-down style (subnav wider than window) to just plain-ol-list (main nav wider than window).

Not sure how elegant it is, but in the end unbind() and removeAttr('style') disabled the dropdowns for me:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() < maxNavigationWidth) {
        $('#neck .navigation').removeClass('sf-menu');
        $('.navigation li').unbind();
        $('.navigation li ul').removeAttr('style');
    } else {
        $('#neck .navigation').addClass('sf-menu').addClass('sf-js-enabled');
        applySuperfish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @JonZa, I have the same problem. Your code is good. But I have some little issue. It's still opening the menu in mouseover event. I want to disable it too. Is it possible. Thanks.